# How to select fields in the expanded field with Microsoft Graph Client for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

As per the Microsoft Graph Client for JavaScript [documentation](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/dev/docs/QueryParameters.md#expand), the client supports the `$expand` query parameter and that works fine.

Since Microsoft Graph API supports selecting inside the expanded field when using (`$expand=attachments($select=name,size)`), how do I do this with the JavaScript SDK/Client?

I've tried something like this, but it returns a plethora of attributes for the expanded manager (something I'm trying to avoid):

```js
client
  .api('/users')
  .expand('manager($select=displayName)')
  .get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is correct but I'm afraid this isn't supported by the API itself. While AAD resources support `$expand`, there are some serious limitations:

1. It is only supported in the Beta version. As for why it is limited to Beta, it's a safe bet that it is due to the next point.
2. You can not use both `$expand` and `$select` in the same query. In other words, not only would `/me?$expand=manager($select=displayName)` fail, so would `/me?$select=id,displayName&$expand=manager($select=displayName)` or `/me?$select=id,displayName&$expand=manager`.

Given the value of data this ends up returning and being restricted to the Beta version, `$expand` is effectively relegated to a handful of edge-case scenarios when it comes to DirectoryObject.

My recommendation would be to avoid expanding the Manager in favor of setting your page size to 20 and constructing a [batch request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching?view=graph-rest-1.0) for each page of data to pull the manager. This allows you to dramatically reduce the amount of data over the wire, keeps the number of outbound calls to just two per page, and can be done entirely in the v1.0 version.

For more information on how batch requests are constructed, please see [Batching](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/dev/docs/content/Batching.md) in the SDK documentation.

Comment: Thank you! I need to give this batching a try. It's a shame though that expanding manager and then selecting just some fields doesn't work. It's so close to the use case I have.